# Ajax.BeginForm not returning to on failure if action name has authorize attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am working on Ajax.BeginForm in MVC with EF. I submitted this form to controller with action name

```
[HttpPost,Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
public ActionResult Index(Register r)
{
--------
}
```

My cshtml code is

```
Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Admin", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "Success", OnFailure = "Failure" })
```

So in my scenario User need to submit form only if he is authenticated, So my action name in controller has authorize attribute. Now when the user doesn't login and try to submit a form, **control** doesn't go to action name and coming to "success" js function.

Please some one help to get this done.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Have a look at the `AjaxAuthorize` implementation out there (one can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888316/authorize-attribute-for-ajax-requests-in-asp-net-mvc-4), but is certainly not the only one available).